# How to use Dictionary<> with Linq externally?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have this dictionary specified in Test1 Project:

```
public static
    Dictionary<string, Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane> paneCollection =
        new Dictionary<string, OfficeTools.CustomTaskPane>();
```

In the Test2 project, by using LINQ, I need to use `paneCollection`.
Right now, it's throwing error as `paneCollection` is `null`.

Comment: Well, judging from your code sample, this can't happen. Something must be changing `paneCollection` to null. What does this have to do with LINQ?

Comment: There's not enough code to say what's happening. As a guess, your Test2 project is accessing `paneCollection` before the line you've posted. Either that or, as Cameron suggested, something is changing it to null.

Comment: ok, in the Project #2, I am trying to fetch paneCollection via LINQ: var query = from dictionary in LexisWord.ThisAddIn.paneCollection where dictionary.Key == objDocument.FullName select dictionary.Value;

Comment: Is it exact query which throw an exception? Strange because it shoud return empty result set

Comment: I would suggest placing a breakpoint on the line that contains the LINQ expression. Examine the value of `LexisWord`, `ThisAddIn`, and `paneCollection`. It's a good bet that one of them is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Each project is executed individually, so the execution of the second project will "reset" your static variable, because it wasn't initialized for that test. Moving to a Singleton should solve it.